# Youtube video setSrc not change in media element player

Tags: youtube, mediaelement.js

I have tried the following code for switch youtube video without page reload:

```
<code>
    function setSource(url, type) {
      var vid = $('#player1').first();
        if (vid.attr('type') != type) {
        vid.get(0).player.remove();
        vid.attr('type', type).attr('src', url);
        vid.mediaelementplayer({
            success: function(media, dom, player) {
                player.play();
            }
        })
      }
    }
</code>
```

And

```
<code>
    $('#idThatSwitches').click(function (e) {
    // switch out player's video source and reload
    player = $('#player1')[0].player.media;
    player.setSrc('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLQl3WQQoQ0');
    console.log(player.media);
    player.load();
    });
</code>
```

The error I get in the console debugger is: `TypeError: this.pluginApi.setSrc is not a function`

Media element version is 3.0.

Comment: you can find the answer here ^^ [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789310/uncaught-typeerror-this-pluginapi-setsrc-is-not-a-function/38791988#38791988)