# Uncaught TypeError: this.pluginApi.setSrc is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to change the source of a mediaelementplayer but I just can't. I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.pluginApi.setSrc is not a function"

I tried all sort of solutions I found on the net, but without a result.
This is the latest code I tried and that got me this error:

```
 var player = $('#player1')[0].player.media;
    player.setSrc('http://youtube.com/watch?v=' + youTubeId);
    player.load();
```

Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: Try changing `var player = $('#player1')[0].player.media;` to `var player = $('#player1').player.media;` - I am sure an ID (`#`) lookup only returns one element. Not an array.

Comment: What is the html element linked to **#player1** ?

Comment: i have already tried that but it also didnt work so when you posted this answer i gott you the exact error its " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'media' of undefined"

Comment: #player1 is the video tag here is my code"<video width="100%" height="400" id="player1"><source type="video/youtube" src="<?php echo $obj->l1;?>" id="youtube_player" />"

Comment: now i switched to this code" var src = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log('play', src);
    player.pause();
    player.setSrc(src);
    player.load();
    player.play();" at least the pause function works perfectly but i still get the same errore as mentionned before concerning the setSrc

Answer (score 2):

for those searching for a solution to this probleme here is my solution
at least it worked for me: so it was all about removing the old player than renitializing the attributes

```
var src = $(this).attr("href"); 
    var type="video/youtube";
    player.pause();

    var vid = $('#player1').first();
    if (vid.attr('type') != type) {
        vid.get(0).player.remove();
       $("#youtube_player").attr('type', type).attr('src', src);
player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1', {success: function(media) {
    //media.play();
}});
```

thanks for all the help i got here^^